about go amqp sdk ,Why is the newChannel method working correctly
when i read https://github.com/rabbitmq/amqp091-go source code
Why is the newChannel method working correctly?
In the recv function, the first parameter is a pointer to a Channel, and the second parameter is a frame.
However, when we look at the recv method, defined as (*Channel).recvMethod, we see that recvMethod only takes one parameter.
Could you clarify how the newChannel method in the Channel.go file is functioning in this context?
// Constructs a new channel with the given framing rules
func newChannel(c *Connection, id uint16) *Channel {
    return &Channel{
        connection: c,
        id:         id,
        rpc:        make(chan message),
        consumers:  makeConsumers(),
        confirms:   newConfirms(),
        recv:       (*Channel).recvMethod,
        errors:     make(chan *Error, 1),
        close:      make(chan struct{}),
    }
}


func (ch *Channel) recvMethod(f frame) {
    switch frame := f.(type) {
    case *methodFrame:
        if msg, ok := frame.Method.(messageWithContent); ok {
            ch.body = make([]byte, 0)
            ch.message = msg
            ch.transition((*Channel).recvHeader)
            return
        }

        ch.dispatch(frame.Method) // termination state
        ch.transition((*Channel).recvMethod)

    case *headerFrame:
        // drop
        ch.transition((*Channel).recvMethod)

    case *bodyFrame:
        // drop
        ch.transition((*Channel).recvMethod)

    default:
        panic("unexpected frame type")
    }
}



Please look up "method expressions", e.g. in the language spec.

The expression (*Channel).recvMethod yields a function of type func (*Channel, frame): https://go.dev/ref/spec#Method_expressions
